# How does GPG2 --verify knows who signed a file and how?

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, information-gathering

When I (clear)sign a file, the output is something like this.

```
$ gpg2 --clearsign test
$ cat test.asc 
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

This is a test!
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2

iQIcBAEBCAAGBQJaCdV1AAoJEMEJof2E4sLlE5YP/2tee+p+3W6rdp49kHXGE6gY
... AND SO ON ...
Olgtxrs9j1BZqvjkjp41
=7Kzg
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Now when I verify this file,

```
$ gpg2 --verify test.asc
```

GPG seems to know which key was used and who signed the file.

From where does it get these information?

Same goes for `$ gpg2 --detach-sign test` :

```
$ cat test.sig
��g����H��cc�~�"V�9n�`6�����|%�xQ��e���Y��/ͩH��j_tGMF�[!��ɍ��
...
���E��4�+�A3g�g��1�CЙ1��k1�Q�`����a��N���}zA)�HŌ�#PF^x�|
```

Comment: Because the signing key ID is in the signature. This is not a security question.

Comment: And what stackexchange-network do you suggest?

Comment: Superuser. There is a migration vote already taking place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature contains the ID of the key that signed the message. It is then searched in your keyring and if the key if found, the details are shown.

Otherwise (eg. verifying on a different machine, where the key is not imported) you will only be given the key id that signed it.

Also note, that gpg2 only knows which *key* signed the file. *Who* signed the files is a slightly different question. You should have verified that the key belongs to the person that it claims to belong to, either directly or through the web of trust. If you didn't verify in any way who is owner of the key, it could have been signed by anyone.